How to create an ER diagram: database design challenge

Is this correct or not?
I'm trying to create an ER diagram for an online food delivery app. Now, I'm unsure if the diagram accurately represents the system.

What standard of correctness are you seeking? You could try building it in a database to see if it would hold the data you want. Is this for an academic exercise?

I'd rename "Food" as "Food Item", to emphasise that it is one item not many. Is the diamond box "have" between Order and Food a many:many? In an ERD you may need an "Order Item" as well as "Order", so the "Order Item" becomes to bridge table to Food Item.

"Menu" also needs work - you need a "Menu Item" so that many items can belong to one Menu. The price is on each item, not each menu.
